# How to find size of input file

Tags: c++, file, while-loop, eof, filesize

I have code written to take data from an input file (it's just a column of ones and zeros) and turn that into however many 32 bit numbers. This works fine when I know how many numbers are in my input file. I'm trying to modify it so that it works for a different input file where I dont know the size, and that's where I'm having problems 
My input file is rad.
I've tried:

```
int x=0;
while(!rad.eof()) {
x++;
}
cout << x;
```

which returns nothing,

```
while(!rad.eof()) {
        rad >> x;
        cout << x << endl;
    }
```

which returns lots of large numbers that are all the same and

```
while(!rad.eof()) {
        rad >> x;
        cerr << x << endl;
    }
```

which returns lots of zeros

The code that works when I know the size of the input file is:

```
/*const int m=32,n=40000; //n isnt 40000, change it so that its the size of    radioactivedata
    int a[n]; // variable to hold each number as it is read from file
    int i=0,j=0; //define variables
    for ( i=0 ; i<n ; i++ ) a[i]=0;
    for ( i=0 ; i<n ; i++ ); rad >> a[i]; //read numbers from rad into array with (>>) operator

    unsigned long Num=0;
    while(j<n){
        i = 0; //reinitialize i and Num 
        Num = 0;
        while ( i<m ){
            Num = Num + (a[j])*pow(2.,i);
            i++;
            j++;
            }

        cout << j/m << "\t" << Num << endl;
        out << j/m << "\t" << Num << endl;
 }*/
```

Any help would be appreciated, please use simple-ish language.

Comment: Since you are using C++, why don't you use a std::vector instead of an array. this way you wouldn't have to worry how many records exist in your file.

Comment: I have no idea how to use std::vector, I have a basic idea of how to use arrays

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `rad` is an [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) you can use [`seekg()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) and [`tellg()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg)

```
  // std::ios_base::ate seeks to the end of the file on construction of ifstream
  std::ifstream rad ("file.txt", std::ios_base::ate);
  int length = 0;
  if (rad) {
    length = is.tellg();
    is.seekg (0, std::ios_base::beg); // reset it to beginning if you want to use it
  }
  // .. use length
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the manual:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/eof/

It contains an example of how to read data. The example can be used to count the data as well.

You can rewrite it like this:

```
std::ifstream is("example.txt");   // open file

int cnt = 0;
char c;
while (is.get(c))                  // loop getting single characters
   cnt++;

std::cout << "Character count in file: " << cnt;

is.close();
```

Comment: `close()` is triggered on `std::ifstream` destructor. Excerpt  from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/close): `This function [close()] is called by the destructor of basic_ifstream when the stream object goes out of scope and is not usually invoked directly.`

Comment: @Patryk I didn't know, thank you. The example in the manual uses it explicitly for some reason.

Comment: already read that page, it dint really help. It just returns 0 (or apparently whatever I initially set cnt to equal, just tried cnt=5 and it returned 5

Comment: @Hester What are the contents of your file? I assume you replaced `example.txt` by your filename? Try using `is_open()` to determine whether or not the file has been loaded correctly. See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/is_open/

Comment: yeah I'm replacing example.txt with my file name, using is_open() I've found that my file hasn't opened properly which is probably the reason nothing is working

Comment: okay I'm dumb and using a bad computer and missed a letter out in the filename. I now have a number which may or may not be correct. Thanks

Comment: @Hester Thank you :) That could happen from time to time. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry about the number of values in the stream.   Simply copy them to a container.   You can check the size of the container, but don't necessarily need to.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iterator>
#include<vector> 

  // and in a function somewhere, assuming rad is a valid stream

std::vector<int> data;

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(rad), 
          std::istream_iterator(), 
          std::back_inserter<std::vector<int> > (data));
```

The above assumes you requirement is to read one `int` at a time, and add them in order to the vector.

Comment: I have using namespace std; before int main() so I don't use std:: before everything (idk that's just what I was taught to do), how do I do the thing you said without all the std:: stuff going on?

Comment: @Hester You can simply remove the `std::` prefix when using `using namespace std;`.

Comment: inside the copy thing too?

Comment: @Hester Yes. Every `std::` prefix will be unnecessary. That is the purpose of `using namespace std;`.

Comment: also, this will give me a vector containing all the values in my input file right? how do I then use the vector? Do I just replace the array with it

Comment: If you google "C++ vector" you will find plenty of reference material, and code samples.